# jQuery UI - Autocomplete Search Remove class name

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have made working autocomplete search function,when data is found,i used `<a>` tag to redirect to another page and when data is not found used `<p>` tag so it will not redirect to another page but the problem is, it is still redirecting.

**jQuery Code**

```
    jQuery( "#id" ).autocomplete({

              source: function(request, response) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: site_url,
                        dataType:'json',
                        data: {
                            tsEmpNum: jQuery('#type').val(),
                            term: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data){
                       //check if no users found
                       if(data.length  == 0){
                          var data=["No Users Found"];
                       }
                       response(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                open: function(){
                setTimeout(function () {
                    jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
                }, 0);
            },
             minLength:2,
              select: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery("#birds").val(ui.item.value);
                jQuery(".form-search").submit(); }
                                    }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

            if( (typeof item.image === 'undefined') || (typeof item.icon === 'undefined') ){ 

                                return jQuery("<li/>")
                                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                .append("<p class='search_not_found'><strong>"+ item.label +"</strong></p>")
                                .appendTo(ul);

                            }else{

                                return jQuery("<li/>")
                                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                .append("<a class='search_found'>" + item.image +item.label + item.icon + "</a>")
                                .appendTo(ul);
                            }
                    };
```

**HTML Output**

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 357px; top: 191px; left: 835.1px; z-index: 2147483647;"><li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1"><p class="search_not_found"><strong>no data found</strong></p></li></ul>
```

How do I remove `class=ui-menu-item` from `<li>` when user search something, so that it does not redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing class ui-menu-item, it is better to handle in the select event.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.item.value=='no data found'){
        event.preventDefault()// cancelling the event prevents the value from  being updated
        return false;// returns from the method without redirecting to other page
    }
    ....
```

Comment: It does not fall under   select: function(event, ui)  but after   .data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item)

Comment: Looks like the if logic is wrong, undefined should not be inside single quotes

Comment: `undefined` is the text that comes up when user search. so single quotes are used.How do i prevent user click inside `if( (typeof item.image === "undefined") || (typeof item.icon === "undefined") `

Comment: when item.image='undefined'  then typeof item.image returns "string"

Comment: When I put `if( (item.image === undefined) || (item.icon === undefined) )` condition and put ` jQuery("<li/>").removeClass("ui-menu-item").addClass("test")` inside condition it adds `test` class but does not removes `ui-menu-item` class.
                                           `